# How to store google map marker data in android app?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an activity that lets the user mark their route. I need to store the route as soon as the user is done with it. I will need to add a save button which allows the user to name the google map file and retrieve it later on the mobile.
[image: Map Marker's]

How can i store the lat/lon of the markers in a file and then retrieve and plot it on the map, when the user opens the saved file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **SnappyDB**

SnappyDB is a **key-value** database for Android it's an alternative for SQLite if you want to use a **NoSQL** approach.

It allows you to store and get primitive types, but also a Serializable object or array in a **type-safe** way.

```
        try {
            DB snappydb = DBFactory.open(getActivity()); //create or open an existing databse using the default name

//Saving List of LatLng
            ArrayList<LatLng> listOfLatLng = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            snappydb.put("LATLNG", listOfLatLng);


//Retrieving List of LatLngs
            ArrayList<LatLng> listOfLatLngNew = snappydb.get("LATLNG",ArrayList.class);


            snappydb.close();

        } catch (SnappydbException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Installation**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.snappydb:snappydb-lib:0.5.2'
    compile 'com.esotericsoftware.kryo:kryo:2.24.0'
}
```

[Reference Link](https://github.com/nhachicha/SnappyDB)